# on wcf type is not expected even though its on ServiceKnownType(typeof(...))

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, serviceknowntype, known-types

i am using third party classes in my service, so i cant edit them.

### third party

```
[Serializable]  
Class B : E  

[Serialazable]  
Class E : A
```

### service

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(B))]  
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(E))]  
fun(A pic)
```

### client

for some reason :

```
proxy.fun(object)
```

throw an exception that B is unexpected and add it to the datacontractSerializer KnownTypes

what reason can it be ?.

Comment: You should post some actual code that actually reproduces the problem, and not this pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you applying the ServiceKnownType attribute on the service contract or the service implementation? The ServiceKnownType attribute is meant to be to be used on your contract interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx